# Is there any solution for C++ goto definition in sublime text 3 on ubuntu16.04?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, sublimetext3, text-editor

I've tried installing `ctags` package in sublime text 3 and `exuberant-ctag` in ubuntu16.04, but it was not feasible to finish goto c++ definition. So I want to know how to be able to jump to c++ definition in sublime text 3 of ubuntu16.04. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## LSP + ccls

[sublimelsp/LSP](https://github.com/sublimelsp/LSP) implements a Language Server Protocol (LSP) for Sublime Text 3, which you can use as the language client for your editor:

> Language Server Protocol support for Sublime Text 3 that gives you IDE features.

[ccls](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls) is an excellent C++ language server which speaks LSP. The ccls author has even [answered a ticked](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls/issues/265) for, particularly, making use of ccls in Sublime Text 3:

> #### Does ccls support sublime text 3? #265
>
> **MaskRay** commented on Feb 15, 2019
>
> ccls speaks LSP. You just need a language client for your favorite editor. For Sublime Text 3, you may try https://github.com/tomv564/LSP

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer largely solved my problem. By the way, I installed [clangd](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation.html) instead of [ccls](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls) because ccls cannot be successfully installed on my system

Comment: @chee happy to help! Yes any C++ language server that speaks LSP will work; I think clangs is starting to become somewhat mature by now (I run ccls/LSP in Emacs myself).